# Expressions for not honoring a deal

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for expressions/idioms to describe:

1) A person who betrays an agreement to sell something to you. Especially because he got a better offer and sold it to someone else instead.

2) The act of doing that. (Would ‘blowing off’ be one?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fail to keep an agreement or to back out of an arranged deal is to '**renege**'.
Someone who behaves in this way is a '**reneger**'.

> **Renege** v : a. Chiefly U.S. To change one's mind; to go back on a promise, undertaking, or contract.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/162420?rskey=jQY5lc&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Tram firm **reneged** on ‘gentleman’s agreement’ it’s claimed

[The Scotsman](http://www.scotsman.com/news/politics/tram-firm-reneged-on-gentleman-s-agreement-it-s-claimed-1-4614605)

> **Reneger** : 3. orig. and chiefly U.S. A person who goes back on a promise, contract, etc.; esp. a person who does this frequently.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/274702?redirectedFrom=reneger#eid)

Answer (score 2):

In British English this is unfortuately common in the property market and is known as [*gazumping*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gazump).

And again specific to British English, but "blowing off" almost always means farting :-)